# Can there be different signatures for AddHandler and RaiseEvent

Tags: vb.net, events

My application has an event for which I need to calculate some result before calling the handlers, and then pass this result into the handlers. I am doing something like this:

```
Dim handlers As List(Of Action(Of String, Decimal))

Public Custom Event MyEvent As Action(Of String, Decimal)
    AddHandler(value As Action(Of String, Decimal))
        If value IsNot Nothing Then handlers.Add(value)
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(value As Action(Of String, Decimal))
        handlers.Remove(value)
    End RemoveHandler
    RaiseEvent(input As String, result As Decimal)
        'perform some calculation here before calling the event handlers
        result = GetCalculationResult(input)
        For Each handler In handlers
            handler.Invoke(input, result)
        Next
    End RaiseEvent
End Event
```

This means that when raising the event I have to pass in a dummy value that gets overwritten within the RaisEvent block:

```
RaiseEvent obj.MyEvent("Input here", 0)
```

I cannot change the signature in the `RaiseEvent` block to only take the `Input` parameter:

> Error BC31137
>   'RaiseEvent' method must have the same signature as the containing event's delegate type 'Action(Of String,Decimal)'.

Is there any way to enable raising an event using a different signature than the handler?